# Voice calling won't work on azure and only local

Tags: azure, voice, npx

output of "npx webpack-dev-server --entry ./client.js --output bundle.js --debug --devtool inline-source-map" :

Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from /home/site/wwwroot

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/getting-started-with-calling?pivots=platform-web

I tried a sample, so the firewall rules are good !

Answer (score 0):

Using cloud shell it worked to make a web-preview.